# fastlane version upgrade number is not showing in my github project

Tags: ios, git, github, triggers, fastlane

hello I am using fastlane for my ios projects. I'm automatically incrementing my version numbers using fastlane increment build number. I include my fastlane file in my pipeline and it works fine. but the version number remains constant in the github project I'm working on. I couldn't solve the problem. can anyone help

Comment: Where do you run the pipeline? Does it commit and push the incremented build number back to the repository?

Comment: I am working on azure devops. but I guess the problem is with git. When the build number increases, my github project does not appear